# Why is this happening in BigQuery Sandbox Environment ? - it only creates empty partitioned tables in BigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

It's same for me as well, somehow when running below DDL statement to create Partitioned Table - it's creating empty Partitioned Tables, Not Sure Why!! -- This is happening in BigQuery Sandbox Environment.

Could someone please tell - why this is happening ?

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE 
stack_it.questions_2018_clustered 
PARTITION BY DATE(creation_date) 
CLUSTER BY tags 
AS 
SELECT id, title, accepted_answer_id, creation_date, answer_count, comment_count, favorite_count, view_count, tags 
FROM 
bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.posts_questions 
WHERE creation_date BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2019-01-01';
```

Comment: Hi, GCP support here. It looks like the issue has to be investigated further. [Can you raise a confidential thread in the issue tracker (referencing this question, as stated in the template) with requested information?](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=491370&template=1161229) After you've created the thread, please share the issue ID here, so we can follow up. Note that issues in that component will only be accessible for you and GCP support.

Comment: Hi There, Thank you for noticing the reported Issue. I have raised the issue tracker number - 226078441.

Comment: Hello! If my answer addressed your question, consider upvoting and accepting it. If not, let me know so that the answer can be improved. Accepting an answer will help the community members with their research as well :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/quickstarts/query-public-dataset-console#limits), in a BigQuery Sandbox environment, the tables and partitions expire after 60 days and this limit cannot be increased unless upgraded from the Sandbox. The reason for the empty partitioned table is this 60 day limit.

The partition expiration date is calculated independently for each partition **based on the partition time**. Since, the new table is created with dates that are more than 60 days old (year 2018, 2019), any partitions with these dates will be dropped. I tested this behaviour by creating a table with recent dates (within 60 days) and the new partitioned table was populated with the data as expected. For more information on partition expiration refer [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-partitioned-tables#partition-expiration).

To remove the BigQuery Sandbox limit, I would suggest you upgrade your project. After you upgrade from the Sandbox, you can still use the [free tier](https://cloud.google.com/free), but you can generate charges. To manage BigQuery quotas, consider setting up [cost controls](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/custom-quotas). More info on upgrading from Sandbox and updating the expiration periods can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/quickstarts/query-public-dataset-console#upgrade_from_the_sandbox).

Comment: Thanks, As per below Link that you shared - [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/quickstarts/query-public-dataset-console#limits)  - This states that the BigQuery Partitioned Tables have limitations while using in Sanbox Environment, rather We should always use the free credits in the trial Account.